# Inject collection of beans to constructor using annotations

Tags: java, spring, configuration, dependency-injection

I am working on spring based project where we use constructor injection and configure context using `@Configuration`.

Here is the simplified example that shows my problem.

I have bean `MyMainBean` that refers to collection of `Foo` beans:

```
public class MyMainBean {
    private Collection<Foo> foos;
    public MyMainBean(Collection<Foo> foos) {
            this.foos = foos;
    }
}
```

Here is the bean `Foo`:

```
public class Foo {
    private final String name;
    public Foo(String name) {
            this.name = name;
    }
    public void foo(String arg) {
            System.out.println("foo (" + name + "): " + arg);
    }
}
```

Here is how configuration class looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyMainBean myMain(Collection<Foo> foos) {
        return new MyMainBean(foos);
    }

    @Bean
    public Collection<Foo> foos() {
        System.out.println("foos");
        return Arrays.asList(new Foo("colletion1"), new Foo("colletion2"));
    }
}
```

When I run this I get exception message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.hello.impl.Foo] found for dependency [collection of com.hello.impl.Foo]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

The message is pretty clear, so although it is not what I need I added the following methods to `AppConfig`:

```
@Bean
public Foo foo1() {
    System.out.println("foo1");
    return new Foo("single1");
}
```

and similar `foo2()`

Now the context runs and beans are wired. But although `foo1()`, `foo2()` and `foos()` are called the `MyAppBean` receives in its constructor collection that contains 2 elements created by `foo1()` and `foo2()`.

I want to get `foos()` working because in my real code similar method retrieves the list of `Foo` dynamically using configuration. I believe that some magic annotations are missing here because I can create list of beans using `context.xml`, but I have to use programmatically created context here.

As a workaround I can create `FooFactory` bean that will expose method `getFoos()` and wire this factory to `MyMain`, however this looks ugly. Is there better solution?

**Remarks**

1. Attempts to add `@Qualifier` did not help
2. Attempts to work with `@Autowire` and `@Resource` instead of constructor injection did not help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both `@Bean` are declared in the same `AppConfig` you can fix your issue like:

```
 @Bean
 public MyMainBean myMain() {
     return new MyMainBean(foos());
 }
```

In case of different `@Configuration` classes the `@Resource` comes to the rescue:

```
@Resource(name="foos")
private Collection<Foo> foos;
```

The `@Autowire` doesn't help in this case even with `@Qualifier`.

Comment: Thanks, Artem. So obvious and elegant... Unfortunately recommendation with `@Resource(name="foos")` did not work for me so far, but the first solution is good enough.

Comment: For the record, injection collections is a special case in the Spring framework. When you ask for `Collection<Foo>`, Spring attempts to locate all beans of type `Foo` and gather them in the required collection type. That's why your foo collection bean is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but here we are :

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    // Answer 1 : Inject the "foos" collection bean  using @Value instead of @Qualifier
    @Bean
    public MyMainBean myMain1(@Value("#{foos}") Collection<Foo> foos) {
        return new MyMainBean(foos);
    }

    // Answer 2 : call directly foos() since @Configuration bean is proxified,
    // "foos" collection bean will only be called and instanciated once (at first call)
    @Bean
    public MyMainBean myMain2() {
        return new MyMainBean(foos());
    }

    @Bean
    public Collection<Foo> foos() {
        System.out.println("foos");
        return Arrays.asList(new Foo("colletion1"), new Foo("colletion2"));
    }
}
```